# Set action to cancel button inside an uisearchController

Tags: swift

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
uiView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
```

How can i add action to the cancel button of the search bar. i want to reload table's data once the user press the cancel button.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the delegate of the UISearchController like so:

```
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
```

Then you can add the method below to your code (which is triggered when the cancel button is pressed):

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
}
```

Comment: when i set searchController.searchBar.delegate = self.  cannot assign value of type 'searchFilterController' to type 'UISearchBarDelegate'

Comment: Have you added UISearchBarDelegate to your View Controller header like `class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate`?